# Enable infinite horizontal panning in Okular

Tags: kubuntu, kde, pdf, okular

## Question

Is there a way to enable infinite horizontal panning (or dragScroll) on Okular in Kubuntu?

## Explanation

Okular has the option to drag scroll (left-click and drag) indefinitely in the vertical direction, however in the horizontal direction it will stop at the edge of the screen (not the okular Window, but the monitor screen), is there a way to enable the indefinite horizontal drag scroll?

## System specifications

- Okular Version 1.3.3
- KDE Plasma Version 5.12.7
- Qt Version 5.9.5
- Kubuntu 18.04 64-Bits

Answer (score 0):

Looking through the settings for Okular, there doesn't seem to be anything, so presumably it's not possible. You might want to submit a bug report requesting this "enhancement". In the meantime, you might want to use the keyboard, or Alt+Scroll, since these are effectively infinite.